# ImagePicker, how to set image again?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Minimal Code:**

```
File _file;

Future<void> _pickImage() async {
  final image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  if (image != null) {
    final file = File("${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/image.png");
    await file.writeAsBytes(await image.readAsBytes());
    setState(() => _file = file); // `_file = image` works though
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), onPressed: _pickImage),
    body: _file == null ? Container() : Image.file(_file),
  );
}
```

---

[Watch video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXBPg.jpg)

As you can see, once I pick the image, it works, but on picking it second time, it doesn't work and I also don't run into any error. Can anyone please help?

Comment: and whats the point in reding / writing if you could simply `setState(() =>_file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera))` ?

Comment: @pskink The reason of doing so is I am using ImageCropper plugin and `image` is first cropped with cropper, after that I save the cropped image in external storage using `File`. That's why i am not directly using `image`

Comment: so most likely flutter does not see any difference when you use the same `Image.file(_file)` since `_file` points to the same location: `await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/image.png` and the new image is not decoded - i would just for test use two names: image.png and image2.png and check if it changes anything

Comment: @pskink I tried debugging it and found that length of `_file` does change (using `_file.readAsBytesSync().length`), that means the `_file` is getting updated with the new `image` but still it isn't updated on `Image.file`

Comment: A file is just a path name to flutter, it won't see the size change I don't believe. As @pskink suggests, try a different name for the cropped image and see what happens.

Comment: @GrahamD said what i just wanted to say: simply try to switch between 2 different names

Comment: @pskink After changing it does show the new image, but the problem is I have a `profile` named image saved in storage, and I only want to update this image. So, I can't use two names.

Comment: @GrahamD Even after checking `if (fileExist) await deleteFile()`, doesn't seem to reflect new image, and I can only save one image in user's phone directory and the name is `profile`.

Comment: so maybe try assigning different unique `key` to `Image.file` widget - deleting the file will not help in any way since the location is still the same

Comment: @pskink Even assigning different `key` using `ValueKey` to `Image.file` didn't help, any other suggestion sir?

Comment: is it unique key? tried `UniqueKey` for example?

Comment: @pskink Still no luck :(

Comment: `child: Image(image: FileImage(File('0.jpg'))..evict(),   key: UniqueKey(),
),
`

Comment: @pskink You're genius, it solved !!! You not only deserve a single upvote or accept but a bounty, let me put this question on 50 bounty and I'll award you :) Feel free to write answer now.

Comment: @pskink I would also like to know the source, how did you find that property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need 3 things:

first you have to use `ImageProvider` and its `evict()` method:

```
var image = FileImage(File('someImage.jpg'));
```

then you need `Image` widget that uses above `ImageProvider` and also assigns a unique `key` in order to be "different" each time `build()` method is called:

```
child: Image(
  image: image,
  key: UniqueKey(),
),
```

and finally after you overwrite `someImage.jpg` you have to call `evict()` method:

```
// part of your _pickImage() method
// here someImage.jpg contains updated content
image.evict();
setState(() {});
```

**UPDATE**: actually you dont need `var image = FileImage(File('someImage.jpg'));` - you can use it directly inside `Image` widget as `image: FileImage(File('someImage.jpg'))` and call `FileImage(File('someImage.jpg')).evict()` after your image is ovewritten

Comment: As I said I'll award you bounty, I just started that, however I'll have to wait for 23 hours to award you.

Comment: I forgot I had the bounty open, got a reminder from SO that it expires in 3 days. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you, this has been bugging me forever. FYI - if you are using a CircleAvatar, you do not need the unique key, you can just call evict().