# Is anybody facing problem with image cache clearing with flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I've tried following methods to clear image cache but none of them worked for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
imageCache.clear();
```

and

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
```

Is anybody facing same problem?

Comment: How did you determine that it doesn't work?  What did you expect to happen, and what did you actually observe?

Comment: When I change the picture It won't update...But when It runs first It works fine.

Comment: *"When I change the picture"* what do you mean by that?

Comment: I created function to  display image which is wrote in application directory using Image Picker.This function allows user to select photo from gallery.And when It's done selected Image will show on the screen.So if user select agian a new photo it have to show newly selected photo.But it shows first one not the new one.So I think that happens because of image cache.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916852/2252830

Comment: Yeah It's kinda similar situation I'll will try that and let you know

Comment: Yeah It solves the problem...