# Removing image from cache when using Image.network

Tags: flutter

Im using Image.Network to display a image based on a URL :

```
ClipOval(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    'http://myurl${userId}.png',
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    key: profileImageKey,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

I'm trying get the user to upload a new profile image, however, i'm retaining the same filename (userid + .png). Once the user has uploaded the image the above is display is not displaying the new image.

I've tried rebuilding the widget using :

```
setState(() {
                                            //generateKey();
                                            profileImageKey = ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100));
                                            userId = userId;
                                          });
```

I've also tried removing the url from the cache using :

```
PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict('http://myurl${userId}.png');
```

However, none of these methods work. Is there a way to update the Image.Network to download and use the new image that was uploaded ?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916852/2252830

Comment: ok gotcha, I need to call evict on the image itself that worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on @pskink's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916852/2252830

The solution to this question was to use the evict method on Image. So I refactored my code to below :

```
Image profileImage;
```

...

```
profileImage = Image.network(
                                    'http://myurl${userId}.png',
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    key: profileImageKey,
                                  );
```

...

```
ClipOval(
                                  child: profileImage,
                                ),
```

...

```
profileImage.image.evict();
                                              
                                              setState(() {
                                                //generateKey();
                                                profileImageKey = ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100));
                                                userId = userId;
                                              });
```

Comment: `new Random().nextInt(100)` is not a best idea - you need a really unique key - random does not provide this

Comment: Is there an alternate I could do ?

Comment: @pskink unfortunately evict doesn't work for me. I thought it did, but after the 1st time the second upload and anything subsequent after that doesn't work. I even physically delete the file on my server (firebase storage) it is still displaying my profile image. Assuming then that this is still within the cache.